# How to embed Song Key & BPM Analyzer on a Website?

Tags: html, web, audio

i am looking for a Webservice that allows me to analyse the BPM and Song Key of a Sample / Audio File. (in best case Open Source)

I am planning to integrate it into my Website (build with WIX , https://www.wix.com/ ) but i really can not find anything like that. It would be great, when it would run via HTML.

I have seen it here https://wavmonopoly.com/pages/key-detector and here https://wavmonopoly.com/pages/bpm-detector

Does anyone has an idea how this could work?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Checkout the web audio api. This should be able to do all those things. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API